# Как узнать логин авторизированного пользователя в MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Есть БД в которой присутствует некое кол-во пользователей с одинаковым уровнем доступа. Каждый пользователь может заносить какие то данные в таблицу черех процедуру, в таблице присутствует поле с указанием логина пользователя который внес эти данные. Как выцепить логин по которому авторизировался пользователь дабы идентифицировать того, кто внес эти данные ? Или может есть какие-то альтернативы для идентификации конкретного пользователя БД?

Comment: *логин по которому авторизировался пользователь* Вот тут не ошибитесь. Есть логин, которым пользователь представился. И есть логин, который использован для аутентификации. Это не одно и то же...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть стандартные функции получения текущего пользователя
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user